# where to get web-design critiques and suggestions?

Tags: resource-recommendations, workflow

Where do you get you design critics for your project, particularly on web design? A friend had suggested to me a website where people critique and give suggestion on your website. But I forgot the name of the website. I'm looking for both free and paid solutions.

A free solution I can think of is to call your friends and let them comment on your design. The downside of it is, not all of them are professional.

Comment: Note: according to an open discussion on meta.graphicdesign, critique *may* be considered on-topic here if it adds to the collective knowledge of the community, i.e if it is part of a constructive question. http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25/asking-community-to-critique-work

Comment: great to know that Jaips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest one I've heard of is http://pleasecritiqueme.com/. It seems like they've stopped providing critiques for whatever reason (have been dark for almost a year).

There might be an avenue here for design critiques, but I think the idea is to provide more definitive answers here to questions that are more black and white than grey.

Really, the best place to get critiques is from your peers and colleagues. You can't beat a back-and-forth critique where you have to defend your work and your design decisions.

More resources:

- Critiques by the world
  http://critiquethesite.com/
- Get the 5 second test by anonymous users
  http://fivesecondtest.com/
- Website Feedback
  http://www.conceptfeedback.com/
- Usability Testing
  http://www.usertesting.com/
- More Usability testing
  http://usabilla.com/
- Even more usability testing
  http://feedbackarmy.com/
- Even more more usability testing
  http://userfly.com/

Comment: most of my friends are not into designs, I also have some friends that are designers but most of them are quite busy. Please Critic Me is good, but I don't want to put the site there, I wanted it to be private. thanks!

Comment: Edited with some more resources. I don't know if they're what you're looking for, but they offer design critiques.

Comment: Mike, Thanks for sharing... :) I Hope this can help other users who are desperately (like me) looking for this resources. :)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

There are sites such at Criticue: http://www.criticue.com/
It's Peer-To-Peer reviewing site i.e. you review a design of a site for a point. Every point obtained is a review on the site/s you submit. 
Criticue is free to use but you don't get feedback instantly. It can take between one to five days to receive feedback.

Another site that would come in handy is UserTest.io: https://usertest.io
They do remote user testing i.e. they have testers who you can choose from to review your site and comment on anything you'd like e.g. you set them a task to sign-up and comment on the design and layout as they browse the page.
Their prices range from $13 - $23 per tester.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

It is not the cheapest option, but the best quality feedback will be from a professional graphic designer, and professionals do not do unpaid work except on a pro bono basis.

I'd recommend working through a directory and finding someone who gives the right impression over one of the bid-for-a-job sites, although I've heard plenty of success stories with the latter.

#### Resources

1. [Freelance Switch Directory](http://directory.freelanceswitch.com/) - search for Graphic designers in your area, you can use keywords to narrow down your search;
2. [e-Lance](http://www.elance.com/) - One of the most popular bidding sites.

Answer (score 1):

MikeNGarrett has posted the best ones. I just want to add that if you pay for a premium [deviantArt](http://deviantart.com) account, you can also use their formal critique request system. Though it will still be public (otherwise no one can see your work to critique it). However, there are so many projects posted on dA, you're not likely to be featured on their frontpage. And even if you are, it'll only be there for a day.

[Behance](http://behance.net) also allows people to comment on your posted projects, but this isn't a formal critique system. Though the designers on Behance are generally of higher caliber than on dA.

There are also a few sites like [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com) that are for designers to post images of whatever they're working on to get feedback. I can't remember the other ones, but I'll post them if I can find them later.

Answer (score 0):

This might be exactly what you are looking for: http://hunie.co - Hunie is a community that connects designers, founders and developers for design feedback.

Good luck,

Comment: Is it right that one has to register to visit this forum? Have one to pay for it? IMO that should be added to your answer to make it better.  BTW: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: You need to register but you don't have to pay - pretty basic. All the community/forum websites require you to register. Thanks Kurt!